# slice() on a long skinny list with multiple entries

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R which is comprised like this:

| year | region | age | population_count | cumulative_count* | middle_value* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | Region x | 0 | 10 | 10 | 50 |
| 2001 | Region x | 1 | 10 | 20 | 50 |
| 2001 | Region x | 2 | 10 | 30 | 50 |
| 2001 | Region x | 3 | 10 | 40 | 50 |
| 2001 | Region x | 4 | 10 | 50 | 50 |
| 2001 | Region x | 5 | 10 | 60 | 50 |
| ...2020 | Region y | 1 | 10 | 20 | 50 |

For each year and region combination I have a discrete cumulative_count (derived from population_count by age) and middle_value (derived from the cumulative_count), again discrete for each year and region combination.

I want to extract from this the row for each region and year combination where the cumulative_count is closest to the middle_value in each instance.
(in the example above this would be age 4 in region x where culmulative_count = 50 and middle_value=50).

I have tried `slice` from `dplyr`:

`slice(which.min(abs(table$cumulative_count - table$middle_value)))`

but this only returns the first instance of the row where there is a match, not all the subsequent year and region combinations.

`group_by(year,region)` doesn't return all the possible year and region combinations either.

I feel I should be looping through the data frame for all possible year and region combinations and *then* slicing out the rows that meet the criteria.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**
I used @Merijn van Tilborg `dplyr` approach, needed only the first match.

Here's a screenshot of the output table - note that variable column is the single year of age and is getting older.

[image: Median Year of Age]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `rank` as it ranks from low to high. So if you rank on the absolute difference your grouped ranks are per definition `1` for the smallest difference. You can simply filter on that value. It also allows to set the ties with `tie.methods`.

**include ties**

```
dat %>%
  group_by(year, region) %>%
  filter(rank(abs(cumulative_count - middle_value), ties.method = "min") == 1)

# # A tibble: 6 x 6
# # Groups:   year, region [4]
#    year region     age population_count cumulative_count middle_value
#   <int> <chr>    <int>            <int>            <int>        <int>
# 1  2001 Region x     2               10               30           50
# 2  2002 Region x     2               10               30           50
# 3  2001 Region y     2               10               30           50
# 4  2002 Region y     0               10               30           50
# 5  2002 Region y     1               10               30           50
# 6  2002 Region y     2               10               30           50
```

**show first one only**

```
dat %>%
  group_by(year, region) %>%
  filter(rank(abs(cumulative_count - middle_value), ties.method = "first") == 1)

# # A tibble: 4 x 6
# # Groups:   year, region [4]
#    year region     age population_count cumulative_count middle_value
#   <int> <chr>    <int>            <int>            <int>        <int>
# 1  2001 Region x     2               10               30           50
# 2  2002 Region x     2               10               30           50
# 3  2001 Region y     2               10               30           50
# 4  2002 Region y     0               10               30           50
```

*other options* include: `rank(x, na.last = TRUE, ties.method = c("average", "first", "last", "random", "max", "min"))`

**using data.table instead of dplyr**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat) # make dat a data.table

dat[, .SD[rank(abs(cumulative_count - middle_value), ties.method = "min") == 1], by = c("year", "region")]
```

**data**

```
dat <- structure(list(year = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L), region = c("Region x", 
"Region x", "Region x", "Region x", "Region x", "Region x", "Region y", 
"Region y", "Region y", "Region y", "Region y", "Region y"), 
    age = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L), 
    population_count = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), cumulative_count = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 
    10L, 20L, 30L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), middle_value = c(50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Thanks @Merijn van Tilborg! The dplyr approach worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could de-mean the groups and look where the value is zero. You probably will have ties, depends on what you want, you could simply use the first one by subsetting with `[1, ]`.

```
by(dat, dat[c('year', 'region')], \(x) 
   x[x$cumulative_count - mean(x$cumulative_count) == 0, ][1, ]) |>
  do.call(what=rbind)
#    year   region age population_count cumulative_count middle_value
# 2  2001 Region x   1               10               20           50
# 5  2002 Region x   1               10               20           50
# 8  2001 Region y   1               10               20           50
# 10 2002 Region y   0               10               30           50
```

**Note: R >= 4.1 used.**

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(year = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L), region = c("Region x", 
"Region x", "Region x", "Region x", "Region x", "Region x", "Region y", 
"Region y", "Region y", "Region y", "Region y", "Region y"), 
    age = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L), 
    population_count = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), cumulative_count = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 
    10L, 20L, 30L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), middle_value = c(50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Ooh...I think I can see that working. I'll give it a whirl tomorrow when I'm back in the office